# Google maps, panel with all ballons to drag/drop on the map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web page which embedded a "Google maps" view.
In this web page, the user must specify several positions on the maps

At this time, I am able to spread the balloons on the map displayed when the user click on a button to be dragged, but according to the zoom it can be very painful to zoom in and out to drag the balloon to a place.

I would like to know if it could be possible to have a panel with all balloons to drag/drop on the map?

My current development :

[image]

My target : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an old demo that I made a few years ago and it might have the functionality you're looking for. The trouble is that it uses the API V2, so you'd have to convert it to V3.

Here:

http://maps.forum.nu/gm_user_defined_marker.html

Comment: Cool, pretty similar! I'm gonna test your demo tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, I did this fiddle based on your idea : http://jsfiddle.net/5cX3t/12/ But I opened another question because I encountered some troubles with IE7 and IE8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365147/google-map-mouseup-event-not-catched-by-ie7-and-ie8-when-dropping-item