# Google map : mouseup event not catched by IE7 and IE8 when dropping item

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am not able to understand why [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cX3t/12/) doesn't work well with IE7 and IE8.

The target is to drag a balloon on the map and catch the mouseup event to retrieve the coordinates where the item has been dropped.

The event is fired correctly on all browsers (IE7 and IE8 included) if the user is not dragging a balloon. But, if the user is dragging a balloon, IE7 and IE8 don't catch the event...

Is there someone to understand what is happening?

**To test the fiddle : do not click on the map, just drag and drop balloons**

Note : IE7 and IE8 have been tested through the IE9 developer options

Comment: I see you're using some undocumented property, (event.latLng.ab). This is never recommended because these properties can change without warning. IE complains about g_coordinate.ab being undefined. Aside from that, beware that Google may serve slightly different API versions tailored for each browser. Perhaps you've seen the .ab property with another browser than IE.

Comment: Thank you about your comment Marcelo. I have just figured it out, see my last post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed. The trick was to place the image in background of a `<div>` and not use `<img>` element

http://jsfiddle.net/5cX3t/17/

Have a nice day